# Retrieve value from object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to take value from object in react.

When I do `console.log(poll.user)` which is user related to this poll

I get first undefined, then

```
{_id: "5bd99816068dee45fddf317e", username: "Karolina"}
```

and I am interested in `_id`

So I try to make `poll.user._id` which gives me undefined....

but if I use  `for in` on poll.user it has values

P.S poll is coming as props

regards

**poll value**

```
date: "2018-10-31T11:55:27.343Z"
options: (2) [{…}, {…}]
question: "Java or Python?"
user: {_id: "5bd99816068dee45fddf317e", username: "Karolina"}
voted: (2) ["5bd99816068dee45fddf317e", "5bd2ef4f755aa221a9cc6f6d"]
__v: 2
_id: "5bd9982f068dee45fddf317f"
__proto__: Object
```

actually this is giving me the value

```
let uu;
if (poll.user) {
  uu = poll.user._id;
}
console.log(uu);
```

Comment: Can you show `poll` value here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get both user id and user name with using && operator like below

```
   const userId = poll && poll.user && poll.user._id;
   const userName = poll && poll.user && poll.user.username;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let userId = null;
if(poll && poll !== undefined && poll.user !== undefined && poll.user._id && poll.user._id !== undefined)
  userId = poll.user._id;
console.log(userId )
```